# What guarantees does libtorrent give regarding file paths

Tags: c++, libtorrent

I need to populate a tree control with torrent's content structure. My code looks like:

```
std::shared_ptr<lt::torrent_info>        torrentInfo;
const lt::file_storage&                  fileStorage = m_torrentInfo->files();
const lt::index_range<lt::file_index_t>& fileRange   = fileStorage.file_range();
for (const auto& index : fileRange) {
    const std::string& filePath = fileStorage.file_path(index);
    // add new item
}
```

Concider the following content of the torrent:

```
Root folder
    |- File1
    |- File2
    |- Folder1
         |- File3
         |- File4
    |- Folder2
         |- Folder3
         |    |- File5
         |    |- File6
         |- Folder4
         |    |- File7
         |- File8
```

Is it guaranteed that iterating `file_storage` as I do, I will get the following effects:

- `File3` and `File4` would appear one after other (may be not preserving original order);
- The same for files (`File5` and `File6`) and (`File1` and `File2`);
- The appearance of files `File7` and `File8` is undefined (I mean which one will appear first).

I suppose it to be true because somewhere in documentation it was said that when you retreiving download progress for files with `torrentHandle.file_progress(lt::torrent_handle::piece_granularity);` you will get the vector of progresses in the exactly same order as in `file_storage`, so it seems that files have to be stored in some predicted permanent way. Thus, one should be able to store any files data for example in vector in the order it was populated consequently while iterating `file_storage`.

Or, may be it should be done in entirely different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files have an order in the .torrent file. That's the order you iterate over the files and that's the order `file_progress()` reports progress for files.

Keep in mind that there may be "pad files". i.e. files that only contain zeroes that are not stored on disk and generally not interesting to users.

It's not clear what "preserving original order" means. Files in directories are not ordered. .torrent creation tool may chose to order files in the .torrent any way they like.

*UPDATE:*

In v2 torrents (and v1-v2 hybrid torrents), the file structure *is* deterministic. Files and directories are ordered per path-element. The ordering is byte-wise and names are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand it correctly, there are absolutely no guarantees about paths' order. Are "Pad files" also in file_storage?

Comment: yes, pad files show up in `file_storage`, you can filter them by asking if a specific file is one, with pad_file_at() https://libtorrent.org/reference-Storage.html#file-name-pad-file-at-hash-file-path-file-size-root-symlink-mtime-root-ptr-file-offset